# RUBY - web scraping - (OpenURI::HTTPError)

Tags: ruby, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to code a simple web scraping in ruby.
It works till 29th url then I get this error message:

> ```
> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:346:in `open_http': 500 Internal Server Er
> ror (OpenURI::HTTPError)
>         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:775:in `buffer_open'
>         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
>         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
>         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
>         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
>         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:677:in `open'
>         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
>         from test.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
>         from test.rb:18:in `each'
>         from test.rb:18:in `block in <main>'
>         from test.rb:14:in `each'
>         from test.rb:14:in `<main>'
> ```

My code:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'nokogiri'  
require 'open-uri'  

aFile=File.new('data.txt', 'w')

ag = 0
  for i in 1..40 do
    agenzie = ag + 1

    #change url parameter 

    url = "http://www.infotrav.it/dettaglio.do?sort=*RICOVIAGGI*&codAgenzia=" + "#{ ag }"  
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    aFile=File.open('data.txt', 'a')
    aFile.write(doc.at_css("table").text)
    aFile.close
  end
```

Do you have some ideas to solve it?
Thanks!

aS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, let me clean it up for you:

```
File.open('data.txt', 'w') do |aFile|
  (1..40).each do |ag|
    url = "http://www.infotrav.it/dettaglio.do?sort=*RICOVIAGGI*&codAgenzia=#{ag}"
    response = open(url) rescue nil
    next unless response
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response)
    aFile << doc.at_css("table").text
  end
end
```

notes:

- using block style File.open means the file will close itself when the
  block exits
- use each to iterate instead of for loop

Answer (score 4):

The code has a minor typo. It should be `ag = ag + 1` and not `agenzie = ag + 1`. I assume happened while you copied the code to stackoverflow, since the code wouldn't have worked with the typo.

I was able to run the code locally, and got the same error. Turns out the [url being accessed](http://www.infotrav.it/dettaglio.do?sort=%2aRICOVIAGGI%2a&codAgenzia=30) (when codAgenzia=30) is not available on the http://www.infotrav.it site; it returns an HTTP error 500.

So the problem is not with your code, but with the remote server ( http://www.infotrav.it )

As slivu mentioned in his answer, you should rescue the error and continue scraping.

Comment: Prakash, now I understand.. problem is that server on http://www.infotrav.it/dettaglio.do?sort=%2aRICOVIAGGI%2a&codAgenzia=30 retrieve some error!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if you can not fix the problem on remote server, try to rescue from error and continue scrapping:

```
begin
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  aFile=File.open('data.txt', 'a')
  aFile.write(doc.at_css("table").text)
  aFile.close
rescue => e
  puts e.message
end
```